# Launch a virtual machine from Excel

Tags: excel, virtualbox, vba

I'd like to launch a Virtual Machine (Oracle VirtualBox) from Excel 2016. I tried with this code but nothing happens, not even errors.

```
 Dim FileName As String
FileName = "D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe"" --comment ""PANT"" --startvm ""2c2e4312-6d7d-4892-8a8f-1471a4d2c79d"""
FileName = "cmd.exe /c  " & FileName
Debug.Print FileName``
'End
Call Shell(FileName, vbNormalFocus)
```

Any suggestion??? Thanks

Comment: Try putting a leading double-quote at the start of the filename.  (You already have one at the end, after .exe.)  So `FileName = """D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe"" --comment ""PANT"" --startvm ""2c2e4312-6d7d-4892-8a8f-1471a4d2c79d"""`

Comment: Thanks! It works! I removed "cmd.exe /c" too.

Answer (score 1):

Your line which says:

```
FileName = "D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe"" --comment ""PANT"" --startvm ""2c2e4312-6d7d-4892-8a8f-1471a4d2c79d"""
```

is creating a string variable which contains the characters:

```
D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe" --comment "PANT" --startvm "2c2e4312-6d7d-4892-8a8f-1471a4d2c79d"
```

You need an extra double-quotation mark at the start of those characters to "enclose" the filename so that the shell doesn't get confused by the space between "Program" and "Files".  So you need the character string to be:

```
"D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe" --comment "PANT" --startvm "2c2e4312-6d7d-4892-8a8f-1471a4d2c79d"
```

and the code needed to create that would be:

```
FileName = """D:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe"" --comment ""PANT"" --startvm ""2c2e4312-6d7d-4892-8a8f-1471a4d2c79d"""
```